# Is there any difference between ViewCompat.setAccessibilityHeading and AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.setHeading for ViewHolders?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, accessibility

When building accessibility into an app, we came across multiple ways of marking  a recycler view item as a heading for accessibility purposes.
We tried following the underlying code, but where stumped.

Is there any functional difference between calling

```kotlin
class MyHeadingViewHolder(viewBinding: MyItemLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewBinding.root) {
    init {
        ViewCompat.setAccessibilityHeading(binding.root, true)
    }
```

and

```kotlin
class MyLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager(...) {
    override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoForItem(
        recycler: Recycler,
        state: State, 
        host: View,
        info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat
    ) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoForItem(recycler, state, host, info)
        val vh = recycler.findContainingViewHolder(host)
        info.setHeading(vh is MyHeadingViewHolder)
    }
}
```

?

As far as we can tell, the final result seems to work the same?

Comment: The first API you reference, `ViewCompat.setAccessibilityHeading`, serves a specific use case.

The second API you use is much more versatile and will allow you to modify the AccessibilityNodeInfo in many different ways.

Comment: @dazza5000 Thank you! We're aware that the latter is a much more broad mechanism, my question is more focused on if there are any differences in the result. Am I correct in interpreting your comment as saying that there is no difference as far as you know?